# Query for all the org configuration regarding reason, subreason, SLA and queues

Tags: apex, joined-reports

I am looking to retrieve, for all the record types, these fields : "Motivo do caso, Submotivo, Local da Ocorrência, Fila Resolvedor, Filas para Conhecimento, Filas 50%, Filas 100%"

My first attempt was to query :

```
SELECT Id, 
(SELECT Motivo_do_caso_Salesforce__c, Submotivo__c, Local_da_Ocorrencia__c FROM Casos__r), 
(SELECT Fila_Resolvedor__c , Filas_para_Conhecimento__c, Filas_50__c, Filas_100__c FROM Filas_de_Atendimento__r) 
from Locais__c
```

And them using an anonymous apex windows run this script :

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Motivo_do_caso_Salesforce__c, Submotivo__c, Local_da_Ocorrencia__c FROM Casos__r), (SELECT Fila_Resolvedor__c , Filas_para_Conhecimento__c, Filas_50__c, Filas_100__c FROM Filas_de_Atendimento__r) from Locais__c
List <Locais__c> locaisList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Motivo_do_caso_Salesforce__c, Submotivo__c, Local_da_Ocorrencia__c FROM Casos__r), (SELECT Fila_Resolvedor__c , Filas_para_Conhecimento__c, Filas_50__c, Filas_100__c FROM Filas_de_Atendimento__r) from Locais__c];
for(Locais__c loc : locaisList){
    system.debug('***** Object Start *****');
    system.debug(loc.Casos__r);
    system.debug(loc.Filas_de_Atendimento__r);
    system.debug('***** Object Start *****');
}
```

But this query is taking too long and exceed the cpu limit. How can i know into a single file about all the configuration of the org regarding reason, subreason, SLA and queues ?

Comment: did you consider a batchable or move into an async? - each has 60 sec CPU limit

Comment: Hi @cropredy i am new to salesforce, i will look at the docs, do you please have any example or link?

Comment: Create a class that implements `System.Queueable` and have its `execute()` method do the query and debug display. Read about queueables in the Apex doc